The model categories of $\mathrm{sSet}$ and $\mathrm{CGWH}$ are Quillen equivalent
By $\mathrm{CGWH}$, we mean the category of compactly generated weakly Hausdorff topological spaces, and by $\mathrm{sSet}$, we mean the category of simplicial sets. I am seeking a reference for the statement "the model categories of $\mathrm{sSet}$ and $\mathrm{CGWH}$ are Quillen equivalent." I have checked Hovey's Model Categories and Quillen's Homotopical Algebra, but to no avail. There is a thesis1 showing the better-known Quillen equivalence of $\mathrm{Top}$ and $\mathrm{sSet}$, but this is not what I want since I am trying to follow Lurie's notation. I think the proof in the thesis can be replicated for $\mathrm{CGWH}$ instead of $\mathrm{Top}$, and the statement itself is intuitive, given that we know about $\mathrm{Sing}$ and $|-|$. There is basically nothing to show once you know that these functors provide an equivalence on the homotopy categories, but I am writing a report and would like to cite a source of this equivalence.

The question is answered in the affirmative by Theorems 2.4.25 and 3.6.7 in Hovey's Model Categories.
